# Batch - Comparing variables

Tags: batch-file, variables

I want to know how to compare variables

My Code:

```
:pass
set /p pass= "Password: "
set read = type Users\%user%\Password\password.txt
if pass = read goto continue
if not pass = read goto passwrong
```

I am trying to make it read the password.txt file and compare it with the password the user typed in for the login system. If the password is correct (matches with password.txt) it will go to the continue script (runs the actual program) otherwise, it goes to a password wrong error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if the password is the first non empty line of password.txt:

```bat
set /p "pass=Password: "
set /p read=<"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PROGRAM NAME\Users\test\Password\password.txt"
if "%pass%"=="%read%" (goto :continue) else (goto :passwrong)
```

And this if the password is the last non empty line of your password.txt file:

```bat
set /p "pass=Password: "
for /f usebackdelims^=^ eol^= %%i in (
        "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\PROGRAM NAME\Users\test\Password\password.txt"
) do set "read=%%i"
if "%pass%"=="%read%" (goto :continue) else (goto :passwrong)
```

Comment: It does not work. I don't think `type` likes to be in a variable. I tried to do `type C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\PROGRAM NAME\Users\test\Password\password.txt` and it works but when i tried doing the exact same thing but making it store in a variable it did not work.

Comment: I haven't put type into a variable, I just replaced your bottom four lines with three. My second line reads the first line of your password.txt file, _(which I will now update with your new path accordingly)_.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Your's was a very good solution but i think the quotes is the issue because i removed the quotes and it worked when i typed in the correct password.